# Android Lint: How to suppress all warnings associated with support library?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-lint, android-appcompat

I am trying to use Android Lint to keep my code running smoothly but since I'm using support-v7-appcompat, Lint returns an enormous, overflowing list of warnings. How can I suppress all of them so I can only see issues with my own app? In the Lint Overflow menu, there are options for "Check all Projects", "check android-support-v7-appcompat", and "check [myapp]" - but clicking [myapp] also shows a vast amount of errors regarding abc_ (support library) and trying to suppress them by selecting them and pressing "ignore in this project" doesn't work! As soon as I click "check [myapp]" again, the same lint errors show up.

I can only assume this isn't intended behavior of lint! What can I do to improve this?

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the option in the android lint menu:

Once "Skip Library Project Dependencies" is checked, that should skip appcompat lint warnings when you are checking your project

[image: lint overflow menu]

Comment: What if some of the projects are library project I've made, and I wish to be warned about them, but don't wish to be warned about third party libraries?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do that, could you (when you are working on the library) just run lint on the library itself rather than on the project that is depending on it?

Comment: yes , you can, and you can even see it on the screenshot you've posted - just use the project you wish to check. However, it doesn't work well as it doesn't consider what's using the library project. this means that if I've set "unusedResources" to warn me, and only the projects that use the library use the resources defined there, I will get a lot of warnings, without knowing which are really unused.