# Fixing android support lib lint errors

Tags: android, android-support-library

It's quite ironic that the official support lib (v7 appcompat) itself has several lint errors such as:

- Android namespace is missing from attribute
- This class should be public (android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.HomeView)

and etc.

So how I do fix those lint errors? It's pretty annoying they are stopping my project from exporting. How did you guys solve this problem? I do not want to change those errors to warnings as I think they are legit errors.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176427/android-lint-how-to-suppress-all-warnings-associated-with-support-library